# asp net core code first, why no nullable's in tables enabled?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Maybe not the place to ask, but not sure where to ask.
So why is it that with a code first aprouch in the latest EF core.
That tables and controllers have nullable's disabled by default?
I altered the migration files to force it.

Am I missing some theoretical principle that nullable's are a bad practice?
(come see huge DB's). Various 3th party controls with model binding also do depend on it.
So i'm wondered and curious of the reason.

Comment: If it's code first, then you are writing the code, and choosing if nullable is enabled or not.

Comment: so why has this been disabled by default, whats the thinking are nullable's bad for EF somehow.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. It is your code that determines nullability.

Comment: Yes ofcourse  they made #nullable disable apparently a default for new solutions just weird to me

Comment: No they didn't, but I'm now confused as to what this has to do with EF?